# Render component from array values in React Native

Tags: arrays, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to render component/function from array values.

**Main function**

```
const GeneratedHistory = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <View style={styles.headerWrapper}>

        <Text variant="headlineLarge" style={styles.headersText}>Historia</Text>
        <Text variant='labelMedium'>Generowane kody</Text>

      </View>

      <View style={styles.mainWrapper}>

        <ScrollView>

          {getItems()}

        </ScrollView>

</View>
 </View>
```

I retrieving values from Firestore and saves what i want to array named **Items**.

```
function getItems() {

  const items = [];

  try {
    firebase.firestore().collection("Generated").where("username", "==", auth.currentUser.email)
      .get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          items.push({
            qrImage: doc.get("qrImage"),
            qrText: doc.get("qrText"),
            time: doc.get("time"),
          })
        });

        items.map((item) => {
          console.log(item.qrText)
        })
      });
  } catch (error) {
    alert('Error occured')
  }


}
```

Nextly i map the array, printing to console and trying to render function named **SingleElement**.

function singleElement(text) {
return (
{text}

)
}

Logging to console work's fine, but i can't render the function.
Screen just stays white.

[image: Screenshoot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have to use async function, in my case, I fetch the data when the window opens and save it to array.

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      todoRef
        .onSnapshot(
          querySnaphsot => {
            const items = []
            querySnaphsot.forEach((doc) => {
              const { qrImage, qrText, time } = doc.data()
              items.push({
                id: doc.id,
                qrImage,
                qrText,
                time,
              })
              setItems(items);

            })
          }
        )

    } fetchData()
  }, [])
```

Then I map the elements and display them in the component.

```
items.map((item) => {
             return <YourComponent key={item.id} text={item.qrText} time={item.time}>
              </YourComponent> 
          })
          }
```